# LineageOS: list of running applications

Tags: lineageos

When I had Android on my tablet (Smasung Note 10) I would long press the chassis button to access a list of running applications; the long press does nothing with LineageOS.

How can I access the list of running applications with LineageOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your settings. For me it is settings -> buttons. There you can specify which button is responsible for which action.

Answer (score 1):

By default, press the original MENU key. This is now the new default on LineageOS across devices that use the legacy MENU-HOME-BACK capacitive key layout.

Note that you can change this behaviour back to what it was by visiting Settings-Buttons - for MENU and HOME, both tap and long-press actions are customizable.

Comment: can you clarify which is the <kdb>MENU</kbd> on this tablet? There is the central chassis button and then two soft back lighten buttons on each side of it.

Comment: The left soft one. As the answer already says, it's supposed to be a MENU-HOME-BACK layout in older ROMs.

Comment: Now I understand. In fact the MENU button, by default, does not bring about the list of running applications, either short or long pressed. This behaviour must be set specifically by the user in the *Buttons* menu, as @tavkomann explains.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't for you - I've owned both the Exynos and Snapdragon variants of Note 10.1 (2014) in the past and it was the default. It is possible that the maintainer of my unofficial build modified the behaviour, but unlikely, as my other legacy devices exhibit the same.

Comment: I can confirm that by default long press for the MENU button is deactivated. Short press is for the context menu.